# filter observable in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, redux-observable

Can you assist me l'm getting an empty array after l try to filter an observable

This is the output l get when l console log

```
Array []
```

length: 0; Array []

This is my shared service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Supplier } from '../components/selectsupplier/selectsupplierObj';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

    private availablesuppliers = new BehaviorSubject<Supplier[]>(null);

    constructor() { }

    loadSuppliers(suppliers: Supplier[]) {
        this.availablesuppliers.next(suppliers);
    }

    getSuppliers(): Observable<Supplier[]> {
      return this.availablesuppliers.asObservable();
    }
}
```

This is where l'm tring to filter by supplierID which l retreive from localStorage

```js
ngOnInit() {
    // call function on page load
    this.report();

    let supplierID = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('supplier'));
    this.SupplierID = supplierID;
    localStorage.setItem('supplierid', this.SupplierID);

    this.Auth.authStatus.subscribe(value => this.loggedIn = value);
    this.shared.getSuppliers()
    .pipe(
        map(suppliers =>
        // console.log("suppliers", suppliers)
        suppliers.filter(supplier => supplier.SupplierID === this.SupplierID),
        )
    )
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log("From shared services", response);
      console.log(this.SupplierID);

    });
}
```

Comment: If you were to comment out `suppliers.filter(supplier => supplier.SupplierID === this.SupplierID)`, do you get any items out?

Comment: hi taylorswiftfan
yes l get all the items

Comment: Excellent. So at least we know up to that line things are working. Are you sure there is a matching SupplierID in the collection?

Comment: yes seems like the filtering line is buggy, but as for the SupplierID it is matching the collection, a previous page lists the items and when user click any item, l send the item's SupplierID to the posted code then retrieve the item's SupplierID from the url. which l then try to filter with in the obs array

Comment: This line: `suppliers.filter(supplier => supplier.SupplierID === this.SupplierID),`:

Can you remove comma at the end and add the `return` keyword in front? i.e. `return suppliers.filter(supplier => supplier.SupplierID === this.SupplierID)`

Comment: Try comparing with only double ==, aka `supplier.SupplierID == this.SupplierID`. Is supplierId a number? The value you get from the url is a string, so you might be comparing 3 ==="3"//false

Comment: thanks a lot guys @DonaldDuck suggestions did the trick,  the value l get from the url is an integer l used parseInt(), but the supplier.SupplierID from the api is a string